# Showing a loop in $S^1$ is epph to a constant speed monotone loop.

Tags: general-topology, homotopy-theory

In proving that any loop $p$ in $S^1$ based at 1 is epph to a constant speed monotone loop, $p_n(t) = \exp (nt)$.

My lecture notes define a lift of $p$ as $\tilde p$ and so as $\tilde p(0) = 0$ we have $\tilde p(1) =n$ for some $n \in \mathbb{Z}$. Then define $g_n(t)$ and an epph from $\tilde p(t)$ to $g_n(t)$ by $$R(t,u) = (1-u)\tilde p (t) + ug_n(t)$$ and then composing that with $\exp$ gives your epph.

BUT, why can't you just go straight ahead and define an epph $$R(t,u) = (1-u)p(t) + up_n(t)$$ because as the loop is based at $1$ we have $p(0) = p(1) = 1$? And so all the properties of epph's are obeyed?

Answer (score 1):

A circle isn't a vector space, so, with $p(t)$ and $p_n(t)$ being points on a circle, it's not clear what point you mean by $(1-u)p(t)+up_n(t)$.

Comment: But it is a topological space? I mean the end point preserving homotopy $R:[0,1] \times[0,1] \to S^1$ defined by $R(t,u) = (1-u)p(t) + up_n(t)$ where $p(t)$ and $p_n(t)$ are as above?

Comment: I'm assuming that this isn't a homotopy, otherwise my lecture notes wouldn't have thought it necessary to use lifts in proving it. They would have gone straight to defining this epph. My question is why is this not an epph? Perhaps it's not continuous?

Comment: It's not a homotopy because it's not defined.  You're taking points on the circle ($p(t)$ and $p_n(t)$) and pretending to multiply them by numbers ($1-u$ and $u$) and to add the results.  The only way for that to make any sense is to regard the circle as being inside a vector space $V$, so that you can do the multiplying and adding in $V$, but even then, the result would just be a point $R(t,u)$ in $V$, not necessarily on the circle.

Comment: Ah OK I understand where this fails now, thank you